# Read a file in "chunks" using PHP

Tags: php, regex

What is the best way to read a file in php by relatively small chunks of data?

For example, read 5MB and then free that memory and read another 5MB

I'm writing a parsing tool in php that needs to read a HUGE file and convert it into CSV.

My problem is that I'm constantly exceeding the allowed memory limit, and raise it is not an option in my environment.

This is part of the code that gets the job done:

```
$i = 0;
$fileName = "test.txt";
$file = fopen($fileName,'r');

while($i <= 2000) {
    $line = fgets($file);
    $streetsheet[$i] = preg_split('@\ @',$line,NULL, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
    ++$i;
}

fclose($file);
$fp = fopen('result.csv','w');

foreach($streetsheet as $key=>$value) {
    fputcsv($fp, $value);
}
```

For example, in the snipped shown above I'm reading the first 2000 lines of the file, and it works just fine.

The problem arises when I change the condition to

`while(!feof($file)){\*....*\}`

It immediately tells me that I've exceeded the allowed memory limit, and then it tells me that the line causing the problem is the one where I'm using preg_split.

So I wonder what's the best way to read the file say... 1000 lines at a time?

Thanks!

**If you're going to downvote at least have the common courtesy to explain why**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're *already* reading it in "parts": You're reading it line-by-line. The problem is that you're sticking all the lines into an array and then dumping the array.

Instead, read a line and output a line and skip the array entirely:

```
$fileName = "test.txt";
$file = fopen($fileName,'r');
$fp = fopen('result.csv','w');

while(!feof($file)) {
    $line = fgets($file);
    $value = preg_split('@\ @',$line,NULL, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
    fputcsv($fp, $value);
}

fclose($file);
fclose($fp);
```

Comment: Gosh.. this is embarrassing, you're very right!
I was only using the other array for testing purposes, and I forgot to remove it once I was done with it, thanks a lot!