# PHP match JSON/CSV into SQL database with many adjustments (cakePHP)

Tags: php, mysql, csv, cakephp, large-files

I want to insert a JSON file (also available as CSV) into a mySQL database using the cakePHP framework. The basics are clear, but the surrounding requirements make it difficult:

1. The JSON/CSV file is large (approx. 200 MB and up to 200.000 lines).
2. The file contains several fields. These fields need to be mapped to fields with different names in the mySQL database.
3. The CSV contains a field named **art_number**. This field is also present in the mySQL database. The **art_number** is unique, but not the primary key in mySQL. I want to update the mySQL record if CSV and database have the same **art_number**. If not a new record should be created.
4. Several fields of the CSV file need to be processed before they are stored. Also additional fields need to be added.
5. The CSV contains an **image_URL**. If it is a NEW record (unknown art_number) to the database, this image should be copied, modified (with imagick) and stored on the server.
6. The whole job needs to run on a daily basis.

As you can see there is a lot going on with some limitations (memory, runtime etc.). But I am not sure how to approach this from an architecture point of view. E.g. should I first try to insert everything into a seperate "import" database table and then run through the steps seperately? What is a good way to get the IDs from the database mapped to the CSV lines? Cakephp is able to perform either creating a new or updating an existing record if I am able to map the ID based on the art_number. Also changing and copying up to 200.000 images seems to be a big issue. So how to break this down into smaller chunks?

I would appreciate if you could help find the right strategy here. What do I need to consider in terms of memory and speed? Doe sit make sense to split the process into different jobs? What/how would oyu do that?

Comment: How is your situation different than _any_ csv import process? You read the file using [appropriate functions](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php) and process the data one row at a time. The import logic is in principle the same whether the file as 1 row or 1 million rows. Make it work with one row first ,and use a [cli process](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/console-and-shells.html).

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. Am I right to assume that PHP CLI scripts do not have limitations in terms of runtime etc.?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I would appreciate if you could help find the right strategy here. What do I need to consider in terms of memory and speed?

- [Use a shell](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/console-and-shells.html) for the import
- [Read the data in chunks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16204453/read-a-file-in-chunks-using-php) of X lines or X amount of data to avoid memory problems and then process these chunks. It's a simple loop.
- If the processing is going to require a LONG time consider using a job queue like [Resque](https://github.com/chrisboulton/php-resque). You can update the status of the progress to the user if needed.

> Doe sit make sense to split the process into different jobs? What/how would oyu do that?

This depends on  the requirements and how long your processing will take and how much your system can process in parallel without going up to 100% CPU usage and effectively slowing down the site. If this happens move the processing to another machine or limit the CPU usage for that process using [the nice command](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nice_(Unix)).

Comment: Thank you for links and advice. So using a not time-constrained CLI with a line-by-line approach is the way to go. I do not have access to the Cake Shell on my server (shared hosting environment). I still want the script to be in the Cake Shell to have access to the rest of the app. But I assume there is no reason not to run the script from my local machine and update the database remote. Copying the images using some kind of FTP connection should not be a big deal (or so I hope...).

Comment: You can do what you propose but it's a pretty poor solution. Get a proper host instead. There are providers like Digital Ocean and VPS Cheap that offer *really cheap* virtual root servers. If people want to run a serious project but are to cheap to spend a few bucks more for a proper environment they won't pay less at the end of the day because other things will rely on fugly workarounds then. So I recommend your client to switch the hosting provider.

Comment: Good advice. Currently the effort related to a migration from an environment where many things are done already by the hosting provider seems a big step. But you are right in saying that it will not get easier by staying longer...